# Passing data within Shiny Modules from Module 1 to Module 2

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shinydashboard

I dont have a reproducible example as the question is more on how modules work. I am trying to understand how to pass some reactive function from one module to the next. I have received replies in the past about using ObserveEvent but they have not seem to work when I am using the reactive value in one module to perform some other operation in another module

```
module1 <- function(input, output, session){

data1<-reactive({
  #some reacttive funcion that produces an output

})
data2<-reactive({
  #some reacttive funcion that produces another output

})  



return(list(data1,data2))


  }

module2 <- function(input, output, session,data1){

observe( data1(), {

  #perform some other functions here using data1().e.g reading or parsing data
})


}
```

So basically I have a module1 that returns two outputs from data1 and data2

I want to use the value of data1 in module 2 and perform some new operation using that value.

I have looked at other answers to similar questions here but I still dont understand them. If someone can help me explain this concept more clearly that would be of great help
thanks for your help

Answer (score 34, accepted):

One possibility is passing the output from one module to the other at construction time. This allows hierachic relationships between modules. There is also the possibility to create memory that is shared between two modules which I will not cover in this answer.

### reactiveValues

Here i created an `inputModule` and an `outputModule`. The `inputModule` recieves two textinputs by the user and the output module displays them via `verbatimTextOutput`. The `inputModule` passes the user submitted data to the output module as a `reactiveValues` object called `ImProxy` (input module proxy). The `outputModule` accesses the data just like a list (`ImProxy$text1`, `ImProxy$text2`).

```
library(shiny)

inputModuleUI <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  wellPanel(h3("Input Module"),
            textInput(ns('text1'), "First text"),
            textInput(ns('text2'), "Second text"))
}
inputModule <- function(input, output, session){
  vals <- reactiveValues()
  observe({vals$text1 <- input$text1})
  observe({vals$text2 <- input$text2})
  return(vals)
}

outputModuleUI <- function(id){
  wellPanel(h3("Output Module"),
            verbatimTextOutput(NS(id, "txt")))
}
outputModule <- function(input, output, session, ImProxy){
  output$txt <- renderPrint({
    paste(ImProxy$text1, "&", ImProxy$text2)
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  inputModuleUI('IM'),
  outputModuleUI('OM')
)   
server <- function(input, output, session){
  MyImProxy <- callModule(inputModule, 'IM')
  callModule(outputModule, 'OM', MyImProxy)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

This approach can be used with `observe` or `observeEvent` as well.

### list(reactive)

If you want to use `reactive` rather than `reactiveValues`, the following adaptiation of the above code can be used. You can leave the `ui` functions as they are.

```
inputModule <- function(input, output, session){
  list(
    text1 = reactive({input$text1}),
    text2 = reactive({input$text2})
  )
}

outputModule <- function(input, output, session, ImProxy){
  output$txt <- renderPrint({
    paste(ImProxy$text1(), "&", ImProxy$text2())
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

### reactive(list)

Again, this will give the same functionality for the app but the proxy pattern is slightly different.

```
inputModule <- function(input, output, session){
  reactive(
    list(
      text1 = input$text1,
      text2 = input$text2
    )
  )
}

outputModule <- function(input, output, session, ImProxy){
  output$txt <- renderPrint({
    paste(ImProxy()$text1, "&", ImProxy()$text2)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I have asked a question using a modification of this code - would it be possible for you to take a look? much appreciated .. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66493273/pass-selected-values-from-outer-module-to-inner-module-in-shiny)

Comment: @Gregor de Cillia, do we need 1 observe or observe event per input, can we list all inputs into 1 ?