# Re-use reactive elements defined in modules

Tags: r, shiny

I'm making an app in which the user can create as many tables as he/she wants and display the code necessary to remake each individual table using `shinymeta`. I can generate the code for each of these tables but I have a problem when I want to create a complete modal that shows every code for each table.

To be clearer, here's a reproducible example:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(shinymeta)

module_ui <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)

  tagList(
    fluidRow(
      actionButton(ns("show_table"), "Show table"),
      actionButton(ns("show_code"), "Show code"),
      tableOutput(ns("table"))
    )
  )
}

module_server <- function(input, output, session){
  data <- metaReactive2({
    req(input$show_table)

    isolate(metaExpr({
      mtcars 
    }))
  })

  data2 <- metaReactive({
    ..(data()) %>%
      select(mpg)
  })

  output$table <- renderTable({
    data2()
  })

  observeEvent(input$show_code, {
    showModal(modalDialog(
      renderPrint({
        expandChain(data(), data2())
      })
    ))
  })

  return(data())
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("launch", "Launch"),
  actionButton("show_full_code", "Show the full code (at least 2 'launch' before)")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  count <- reactiveValues(value = 0)

  observeEvent(input$launch, {
    count$value <- count$value + 1
    insertUI(selector = "#show_full_code",
             where = "afterEnd",
             ui = module_ui(paste0("x", count$value)))
    callModule(module_server, paste0("x", count$value))
  })

  #### "Merge" the single code modals in one big
  observeEvent(input$show_full_code, {
    showModal(modalDialog(
      renderPrint({
        expandChain(x1_data)
      })
    ))
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

When you click on "Launch", two buttons are generated and you can display a table ("Show table") and the code to remake this table ("Show code"). You can click on "Launch" indefinitely and the table will be named `x1_data`, `x2_data`, etc.

However, when I try to generate the code that unites every individual code (by clicking on "Show the full code"), `x1_data` is not found. Using `x1_data()` does not work either. I'm not a fan of asking two questions in one post but I will do this now:

- How can I access the reactive elements created inside modules?
- How can I "merge" every individual code in a big one?

Also asked on [RStudio Community](https://community.rstudio.com/t/re-use-reactive-elements-passed-in-modules/53842)

**Edit:** following a comment, I add a second reactive expression in my example, so that I can't use `return` on both of them.

Comment: You can have the module server function `return` the dataframe object: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46596172/r-shiny-how-can-i-return-reactive-values-from-a-shiny-module-to-the-master-serv

Comment: adding ```return(data())``` at the end of the module does not solve it, and even if it did, I have several reactive expressions and I can't return all of them (I edited the post)

Comment: You can return a list of reactive data frames and reactive vectors and whatever else. I do this all the time to manage module data and user inputs.

Comment: when I add ```return(list(data(), data2()))``` at the end of the module part, ```x1_data``` (in ```expandChain```) is still not found. Do you have a working example to share?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I came up with an answer that has the module return the `expandChain()` results rather than trying to render them again in the server:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(shinymeta)

module_ui <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)

  tagList(
    fluidRow(
      actionButton(ns("show_table"), "Show table"),
      actionButton(ns("show_code"), "Show code"),
      tableOutput(ns("table"))
    )
  )
}

module_server <- function(input, output, session){
  data <- metaReactive2({
    req(input$show_table)

    isolate(metaExpr({
      mtcars 
    }))
  })

  data2 <- metaReactive({
    ..(data()) %>%
      select(mpg)
  })

  output$table <- renderTable({
    data2()
  })

  observeEvent(input$show_code, {

    showModal(modalDialog(
      renderPrint({
        expandChain(data(), data2())
      })
    ))


  })
  ########################################
  ### create list of reactive objects ####
  ########################################
  return(list(
    expandChain(data(), data2())
  )
  )

}

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("launch", "Launch"),
  actionButton("show_full_code", "Show the full code (at least 2 'launch' before)")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  count <- reactiveValues(value = 0)


  observeEvent(input$launch, {
    count$value <- count$value + 1
    insertUI(selector = "#show_full_code",
             where = "afterEnd",
             ui = module_ui(paste0("x", count$value)))
     callModule(module_server, paste0("x", count$value))


  })

  #### "Merge" the single code modals in one big list object
  my_data <- reactive({
    req(count$value)

    my_set <- 1:count$value

    ### lapply through the different name spaces so all are captured ###     
    final <- lapply(my_set, function(x){
      temp <- callModule(module_server, paste0("x", x))
      return(temp)
    })

    return(final)
  })


  #### "Merge" the single code modals in one big
  observeEvent(input$show_full_code, {
    showModal(modalDialog(
      renderPrint({

        temp <- sapply(unlist(my_data()), function(x){
          print(x)
        })

      })
    ))
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: thanks! sometimes I have to click twice on the "show full code" button but that is not a big deal. Just one more thing, do you know how to remove the ```[[1]]```, ```[[2]]```... in the code that is printed?

Comment: Adjusted the answer to use `sapply` to print out the output

Comment: perfect, thanks a lot (just have a little problem at the end, there are a parenthesis and a bracket missing)

Comment: Copy and paste fail - should be fine now.