# Shiny: Getting (reactive) value from one module and passing it (as a reactive) to the callModule() function of another module

Tags: r, shiny

What I'm trying to do is pass a value (the choice encapsulated in a radio button) of one module to another (which takes the choice and spits out a graph appropriate to it).

I've read a lot about `reactive()` and related functions, and still don't really know how to use the function appropriately. It seems to me that one should only have to call `reactive()` *once*, when declaring something—and that something will be reactive through out it's whole usage. This doesn't seem to be the case, though:

**server function of first module:**

```
# Return the choice user selects
sidePanel <- function(input, output, session) {
    selected_graph <- reactive({input$selected_graph})
    return(selected_graph)
}
```

**server function of second module:**

```
source('graph_choices.R')
mainPanel <- function(input, output, session, data, choice) {
        output$graph <- renderPlot({
            match.fun(reactive(choice))(data)
        })
}
```

**graph_choices.R**

```
choice_1 <- function(data) {
ggplot(data, aes(x=time, y=score)) + geom_point()

choice_2 <- function(data) {
ggplot(data, aes(x=eyelashes, y=score)) + geom_bar(stat='identity')
```

**server function of app**

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
    file_name <- parseQueryString(isolate(session$clientData$url_search))
    sounds <- read.csv(paste('/srv/tmp_data/', file_name, sep=""), encoding='UTF-8')
    sounds_trimmed <- filter(sounds, score != -1)
    sidePanel <- callModule(sidePanel, "side")
    mainPanel <- callModule(mainPanel, "main", data=sounds_trimmed, choice=sidePanel())
}
```

So, what's going on here is that the first module sets up the side-panel with two radio buttons—one whose value is `choice_1` and one whose value is `choice_2`. Upon selecting the button, the `return` bit spits out the choice, and it's passed to the server function of the second module, which spits out the appropriate graph.

I know that my problem is in my usage of `reactive()` because, without it, everything "works" well (the first radio button is selected by default, that choice is given to the second module, and the appropriate graph is shown.) But, when I change the radio button, nothing happens.

I've a bunch of different permutations on where to put `reactive`, and get different results sometimes (once I enclosed the second module's output with `reactive()` and seemed like something changed, but still nothing updated).

Would anyone mind helping me out?

---

I've also tried `mainPanel <- callModule(mainPanel, "main", data=sounds_trimmed, selected_graph=sidePanel)` with `match.fun(selected_graph())(data)` as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46555355/passing-data-within-shiny-modules-from-module-1-to-module-2) question; the graph prints out (as before, but doesn't change upon changing the button).

Comment: I think you may have more luck if you provide a reproducible example (a minimal example of your ui+server that can be run).  You have a lot of information here that's quite hard for me to follow.

Answer (score 0):

I had to make some guesses in order to come up with an app that hopefully illustrates how to solve your problem. I renamed `mainPanel` to `mP` to not avoid name collusions with `shiny::mainPanel` (probably irrelevant).

The key is to map from the choice given via `selectInput` to the plotting function which I did with

```
plotFun <- switch(choice(), choice_1 = choice_1, 
                  choice_2 = choice_2, stop("invalid choice()"))
```

I prefer to use explicit mapping and really don't see a lot of cases where functions like `base::get` are required.

About the usage of `reactive`: You want to make sure that all "dynamic" inputs and outputs for/from your module are created with `shiny::reactive`. Then you evaluate them after passing. There are other ways to pass "dynamic" objects, but this is the recommended way given all the documentation I saw about modules so far.

```
library(shiny)

choice_1 <- function(data) 
  plot(factor("choice 1"))
choice_2 <- function(data) 
  plot(factor("choice 2"))

sidePanelUI <- function(id) {selectInput(NS(id, "selected_graph"), "graph", 
                                         c("choice_1", "choice_2"))}  
sidePanel <- function(input, output, session) {
  reactive({input$selected_graph})
}

mPUI <- function(id) {
  plotOutput(NS(id, "graph"))
}
mP <- function(input, output, session, data, choice) {
  output$graph <- renderPlot({
    plotFun <- switch(choice(), choice_1 = choice_1, 
                      choice_2 = choice_2, stop("invalid choice()"))
    plotFun(data)
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidePanelUI("side"),
  mPUI("main")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  sidePanel <- callModule(sidePanel, "side")
  callModule(mP, "main", data = mtcars, choice = sidePanel)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```