# Pass selected values from outer module to inner module in SHINY

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I have been studying the following question.

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46555355/passing-data-within-shiny-modules-from-module-1-to-module-2)

However, I am stuck on a variation of the problem:

I am trying to pass only *certain values* (**vals**) from the inputModule to the outputModule.
However, my inputModule also has an additional rendered output. This seems to be preventing the app from working.
I my real life app, the inputModule needs to pass data to a nested (outputmodule) and produces additional output and UI as well.

How can I restrict callModule or MyImProxy to only the **vals** and not pass output$mytext to my outputModule in the app server call?

Is is possible to have this code run while keeping the `output$mytext` in the inputModule`?

Many thanks

````
library(shiny)

inputModuleUI <- function(id){
          ns <- NS(id)
          wellPanel(h3("Input Module"),
                    textInput(ns('text1'), "First text"),
                    textInput(ns('text2'), "Second text"), 
                    textInput(ns('text3'), "Third text")
                    ), 
          
          verbatimTextOutput(ns("mytext"))
}

inputModule <- function(input, output, session){
          vals <- reactiveValues()
          observe({vals$text1 <- input$text1})
          observe({vals$text2 <- input$text2})
          return(vals)
          
    #I need this output to stay in the inputModule
          
          output$mytext <- renderPrint({
                    
                    paste(input$text3)
                    
          })
          
          
          
}

outputModuleUI <- function(id){
          tagList(
                    inputModuleUI('IM'),
                    wellPanel(h3("Output Module"),
                              verbatimTextOutput(NS(id, "txt")))
          )
}
outputModule <- function(input, output, session, ImProxy){
          output$txt <- renderPrint({
                    paste(ImProxy$text1, "&", ImProxy$text2)
          })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
          outputModuleUI('OM')
)   
server <- function(input, output, session){
    
#here is where I need to only pass vals to MyImProxy...

          MyImProxy <- callModule(inputModule, 'IM') 
          callModule(outputModule, 'OM', MyImProxy)
}

shinyApp(ui, server) ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem lies in the `inputModuleUI`. If you combine several ui elements, wrap it with `tagList`:

```
inputModuleUI <- function(id){
      ns <- NS(id)
      tagList(
      wellPanel(h3("Input Module"),
                textInput(ns('text1'), "First text"),
                textInput(ns('text2'), "Second text"), 
                textInput(ns('text3'), "Third text")
      ), 
      
      verbatimTextOutput(ns("mytext"))
      )
}
```

Comment: That works thank you! but I have a second question - how could I put the inputModuleUI into the outputModuleUI - why doesn't this work?     I have edited the original question

Comment: I think for this you have to directly call the `inputModule` server function within the `outerModule` server function and also assign the returned values there